# Offline MailDir Restoration Advice

Tags: email, backup, rsync

Situation:

I have an offline backup of gigs worth of email.  After some reading, I confirmed that the email can be restored to MailDir on my new server via rsync.

My rather basic question:

**File Names...**

In my offline backup directory all the emails contains the old server name in the file name of the emails:
[image: ![image|690x250](upload://vUjwPQl63yodAvKLVY6BBuHQZZ5.png)]

As my current hostname is `admin.example.com`, should I first set-up some type of batch `search and replace`  in order to replace `server1.old-example.com` with `admin.example.com`..... then perform the rsync from offline backup to online MailDir?

If yes, any recommended method?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hostname doesn't matter, everything up to the first `,` is simply a unique ID without any defined format. (The purpose of including a hostname is to ensure filename uniqueness – e.g. when multiple MX servers deliver into the same Maildir over NFS, this ensures that even messages delivered at the exact same moment will not collide.)

So just dump your entire Maildir into the new server and everything should work; the new IMAP server will pick up messages found in `cur/` regardless of any hostnames. (As mentioned in comments, though, make sure the UID/GID ownership is correct.)

(However, I would probably clean out old server-specific junk such as "dovecot.index" files before uploading to the new server.)

Be careful to not miss subfolders – they're usually stored as hidden subdirectories, e.g. the folder "Archive/2022" would be `Maildir/.Archive.2022/`. The way subfolders are stored **may** differ between servers.

---

If direct restore fails, you can upload messages via IMAP instead (allowing the server to store them the way it wants), e.g. using the `mutt` or `neomutt` terminal-based mail apps:

1. Run `mutt -f ~/Mail_backup/` to open a local Maildir (don't include the "cur/" part!).
2. Use <kbd>Shift+T</kbd> `.` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select ("tag") all messages.
3. Use <kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>Shift+C</kbd> to "copy", then provide the target IMAP server's URL.

   ```
   Copy tagged to mailbox: imaps://user@mail.example.com/INBOX
   ```

   Note: Subfolders might be named either `Archive.2022` or `Archive/2022` depending on your IMAP server type. (It could even be `INBOX.Archive.2022` if it's a Courier server, which insists on placing all subfolders underneath INBOX.)
4. After all messages are uploaded, <kbd>x</kbd> to exit without saving changes (just in case you accidentally made some) and go back to step 1 for restoring the remaining subfolders.

---

Comment: Thx for your reply... I will try the 'dump it all approach' with some smaller accounts... If things go awry, I may request you to expand upon mutt / neomutt usage as I havn't the slightest clue what those are.   Or possible other methods.. because going folder by folder would requires months of time. thx again... wish me luck

Comment: You also need to make sure the correct person owns the files - likely not an issue to you, but things break on my setup when I move (server classified) spam files around unless I change ownership of them.

Comment: @davidgo  I just solved that exact problem and perfectly restored one of my prior mailboxes... except for the fact old emails are now listed as "unread".... thx for the tip..

Comment: @user1686 You were dead on right... the dump it all approach work perfectly thanx.